# XML to Word Convertor in PHP

Tags: php, xml, ms-word

I need to convert the XML into word file. I searched few things not getting anything exactly. Can you please help me?

Comment: do you have the schema ?

Comment: This is not a programming question . Request to move to superuser

Answer (score 0):

Look here :
http://news.oreilly.com/2008/08/importing-xml-documents-into-w.html

http://www.infoworld.com/t/applications/open-xml-translator-word-available-274

http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.asp?ID=969

Comment: Thanks Gaurav Shah for your links.

i need  PHP script to convert the XML to word. Do you have any bro?

Comment: You can upvote and/or accept answer if it solves your problem.. Thats the way of thanks at this site :)